# Почему не работает цикл Python3

Tags: python-3.x

Сканирую компьютеры в локально сети

```
ip_subnet = ["192.168.4.", "192.168.5."]

def scan_lan(ip_subnet):
    i = 0
    for ip in ip_subnet:
        while i <= 255:
            ip_adr = ip + str(i)
            response = subprocess.call(["ping", "-n", "1", "-w", "200", ip_adr])
            if(response == 0):
                try:
                    wql = 'SELECT *  FROM Win32_computerSystem'
                    c = wmi.WMI(ip_adr, user=config.admin, password=config.password)
                    for item in c.query(wql):
                        check_in_db_if_ping(item.DNSHostName, ip_adr)
                except:
                    pass
            else:
                 check_in_db_if_not_ping(ip_adr)
            i += 1
```

Создал лист с подсетями и по идеи он должен перебираться из for. Но происходит следующее цикл доходит до 192.168.4.255 и останавливается, а должен по идее перейти на следующий элемент списка 192.168.5. , но этого не происходит. Где я не прав?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что вы забываете обнулять `i` после прохождения цикла `while`. Соответственно когда доходит до элемента списка `"192.168.5."`, `i` уже будет равен 256 и `while` будет пропущен. Обнуляйте `i` после `while`:

```
ip_subnet = ["192.168.4.", "192.168.5."]

def scan_lan(ip_subnet):
    i = 0
    for ip in ip_subnet:
        while i <= 255:
            ip_adr = ip + str(i)
            response = subprocess.call(["ping", "-n", "1", "-w", "200", ip_adr])
            if(response == 0):
                try:
                    wql = 'SELECT *  FROM Win32_computerSystem'
                    c = wmi.WMI(ip_adr, user=config.admin, password=config.password)
                    for item in c.query(wql):
                        check_in_db_if_ping(item.DNSHostName, ip_adr)
                except:
                    pass
            else:
                 check_in_db_if_not_ping(ip_adr)
            i += 1
        i = 0 # << это самое
```

Comment: В данном коде более естественным было бы не добавлять ещё одно обнуление переменной, а внести то, которое уже есть вначале, внутрь первого цикла.

Answer (score 3):

Идеологически более правильно использовать в данном случае не цикл while, а цикл for с вот такой первой строчкой:

```
for i in range(0, 256):
    # здесь ваш код
```

Этот синтаксис предпочтителен хотя бы тем, что в строке заголовка видно сразу всё, что будет влиять на ротацию цикла и вы можете быть уверенными, что не забудете обнулить или увеличить на единицу переменную цикла.

Answer (score 1):

```
def scanLan(ip, rr=tuple(str(_) for _ in range(1, 256))):
    for i in rr:
        ip_adr = ip + i
        response = subprocess.call(["ping", "-n", "1", "-w", "200", ip_adr])
        if(response == 0):
            try:
                wql = 'SELECT *  FROM Win32_computerSystem'
                c = wmi.WMI(ip_adr, user=config.admin, password=config.password)
                for item in c.query(wql):
                    check_in_db_if_ping(item.DNSHostName, ip_adr)
            except:
                pass
        else:
             check_in_db_if_not_ping(ip_adr)

ip_subnet = ["192.168.4.", "192.168.5."]
map(scanLan, ip_subnet)
```